# C# and Android Socket image sending

Tags: c#, android, image, sockets

i'm trying to do a new application for android. I connected my C# app with Android app by sockets and i can send texts easily. However, the point i couldn't do is sending pictures. Client Android app will send a text and my desktop app will answer with a bitmap image. I tried Base64 coding but it's not working for me. I'm stuck.

### ***C# server response code***;

```
else if(text.ToLower() == "resim")
{
    response = "resim gönderiliyor...";
    byte[] text_ = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
    socket.BeginSend(text_, 0, text_.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    byte[] buffer = ToBase64String(ScreenCaptured(), ImageFormat.Bmp);
    socket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
}
```

### ***ToBase64String function;***

```
public string ToBase64String(Bitmap bmp, ImageFormat imageFormat)
    {
        string base64String = string.Empty;


        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(memoryStream, imageFormat);


        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] byteBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();


        memoryStream.Close();


        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteBuffer);
        byteBuffer = null;


        return base64String;
    }
```

### ***Android Client Side;***

```
public void addListener(OnListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

static Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (flag) {
            bmp = SixtyFourBaseToBitmap(msg.obj.toString());
            if(bmp != null)
            {
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
            else
            {
                kq += msg.obj.toString() + "\r\n";
                textResponse.setText(kq);
            }
        }

    }
};
public static Bitmap SixtyFourBaseToBitmap(String codedString)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(codedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

        return decodedByte;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonConnect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.connect_button);
    settings_button_ = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
    textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.response_img);

    preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = preferences.edit();
    ipbilgisi=preferences.getString("ip", "IP Girin");
    portBilgisi= preferences.getString("port", "Port Girin");


    buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myClientTask = new ClientTask(ipbilgisi, portBilgisi);
            myClientTask.execute();
        }
    });

}
public void goSettings(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
public class ClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements
        OnListener {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    PrintWriter out1;


    ClientTask(String addr, String port) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            out1 = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            //out1.print("Hello server!");
            out1.flush();

            BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            do {
                try {
                    if (!in1.ready()) {
                        if (message != null) {
                            MainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1,
                                    "Server: " + message).sendToTarget();
                            message = "";
                        }
                    }
                    int num = in1.read();
                    message += Character.toString((char) num);
                } catch (Exception classNot) {
                }

            } while (!message.equals("bye"));

            try {
                sendMessage("bye");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            if (socket.isClosed()) {
                flag = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bağlantı Hatası!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void listener(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sendMessage(text);
    }

    void sendMessage(String msg) {
        try {
            out1.print(msg);
            out1.flush();
            if (!msg.equals("bye"))
                MainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1, "Me: " + msg)
                        .sendToTarget();
            else
                MainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1,
                        "Ngắt kết nối!").sendToTarget();
        } catch (Exception ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void send(View v) {
    addListener(myClientTask);
    if (listener != null)
        listener.listener(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1))
                .getText().toString());
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.listener("bye");
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.listener("bye");
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    super.onStop();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: Nowhere i see your client send a command to the server. The server sends a text and a base64 text. Where in your client are you separating them? `in1.read()` reads only one character at a time. You are relying on `in1.ready()` to have received every thing the server sent. Did you check that? Don't decode the base 64 string but inspect if it is the same as sent. Length and so. You did not tell where things go wrong.

Comment: I'm sending a command to server with editable text box. I took the code from the net and modified a little bit, actually i don't know java coding and i'm trying to figure out how to achieve my goal.